# Multiple bounds on type with method invocation conversion

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Consider this small test class:

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Test {

    // CAN modify this constructor interface
    public <T extends Runnable & Comparable<T>> Test(List<T> l) {
        setList((List<Runnable>)l);   // <-- (a) warning
        setList(l);                   // <-- (b) error
    }

    // CANNOT modify this interface
    public abstract void setList(List<Runnable> l);
}
```

This succinctly represents my problem, in that I want to use generic methods which take objects of type `T` (which are both `Runnable` and `Comparable<T>`) like `Test`'s constructor, but I am constrained to using other methods with interfaces like that of `setList` to take collections of `T`.

**(a)** Why does the compiler warn about an unchecked conversion to `List<Runnable>` when `l` is an instance of `List<T>` where `T` extends, and has type erasure, of `Runnable` (as per [JLS SE7 §4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6))?

**(b)** The compiler raises the following error:

```
error: method setList in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
    setList(l);   // <-- compiler error
    ^   
required: List<Runnable>   
found: List<T>   reason: actual argument List<T> cannot be converted to 
                         List<Runnable> by method invocation conversion   
where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Runnable,Comparable<T> declared in constructor <T>Test(List<T>)
```

My understanding here is that [method invocation conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) couldn't convert `T` to `Runnable` because perhaps this is considered a narrowing operation, but this is counter-intuitive, as I expected it could as `T` intersects both `Runnable` and `Comparable<T>`.

Must I resort to unchecked conversions (a) of instances of `T` to `List<Runnable>` in this case?

**EDIT**

The answer turns out to be yes, as Bhesh has pointed out below, generic types are invariant in Java. If I could use the following, error (b) would not occur:

```
public abstract void setList(List<? extends Runnable> l);
```

For more information, see [this excellent tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html) and this section on capture conversion in the [JLS SE7 §5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `T` is-a `Runnable` but `List<T>` is-not-a `List<Runnable>`. *Generic types are invariant in Java.*

b) Reason is the same as the above. *Method parameters are also invariant in Java.* (Note: The method arguments are covariant.)

---

The cast in `setList((List<Runnable>)l);` should be safe, because we know that `T` is always going to be something that implements `Runnable`. This is the type of situation for which the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` exists.

---

Still a problem could be (depending upon your situation) that you are invoking an overridable method from a constructor.